# Load events for embedded elements

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I do an online `onload` event for embedded objects, that seems to work but I can't seem to get the `load` event working through `addEventListener`. Is this expected?

Comment: document.addEventListener('load',foo,false); ain't it work?

Comment: in IE we have to use "attachEvent", I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, but it may be browser dependent.

windows and images and iframes define their load events with addEventListener and attachEvent, but other load events are browser specific.

A script or link element's onload doesn't attach in IE, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

try

`$("embed").ready(function(){ ... });`

Answer (score -1):

could always set like this:

```
document.getElementById("objectId").onload = function(){ ... }
```

Comment: @Geuis already said that works.  They are wondering why `addEventListener` doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

jQuery is perhaps the best way to go with this.

```
$("embed").load(function(){
   // enter code here
})
```

Comment: Interesting. Might be my fault, I wasn't 100% sure if `load` was an event to the `embed` element.

Comment: @clarkk: Interesting, but isn't that method different in implementation depending on the version of jQuery one uses?

Answer (score -2):

jQuery `on/bind/load` won't be fired for embed elements, while `ready` works but not after rendered when using Chrome, if you want to listen to the stage after rendering embeded elements, you may have to use pure js to add handlers.