# Add event listener to embed JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, embed

I'm trying to add an event listener to an embed object but still not success, this is the piece of bits I'm trying now.

```
var obj,
    url = "http://www.google.com",
    container = document.getElementById("contractFrameContainer");

obj = document.createElement('embed');
obj.setAttribute("type", "application/pdf");
obj.setAttribute("id", "pdf1");
obj.style.width = '100%';
obj.height = heightBody;
obj.setAttribute("src", url);       
obj.addEventListener("load", pdfLoad, false);

function pdfLoad() {
    // do something...
}

container.appendChild(obj);
```

PD: I'm using IE 11

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740860/javascript-load-events-for-embed-elements

Comment: i will edit with my appending to DOM

Comment: The link don't have what i need, i'm trying with embed not an object :

Comment: Maybe i'm trying an event that IE does not support, which would be the event to know when the embed content loads?