# Detect if HTML embed has been embedded

Tags: html

I use an `embed` to embed a pdf document:

```html
<embed class="native-pdf" src="https://sample-videos.com/pdf/Sample-pdf-5mb.pdf" type="application/pdf" title="document.pdf" style="width: 100%;>
```

Now I'd like to detect, whether the embed has been loaded, so I can provide a suitable fallback. However, I can't control the inner content, so I can just peek "from the outside". Here are some values I tried on both (loaded and not loaded):

```js
const embedObj = document.querySelector('.native-pdf')
embedObj.childElementCount // 0 on both
embedObj.hasChildNodes() // false on both
embedObj.style.width // "100%" on both
embedObj.contentWindow // undefined on both
$(embedObj).contents() // undefined on both
```

Using `onloaded` does neither fire for both, while `$(embedObj).ready()` actually fires for both, so I can't distinct between loaded and unloaded.

**Background**

When the embed is blocked in case of

```
Failed to load 'https://sample-videos.com/pdf/Sample-pdf-5mb.pdf' as a plugin, because the frame into which the plugin is loading is sandboxed.
```

then the embed as element still exists but I'd like to automatically fall back to pdf-js (without requiring the user to interact).

Comment: Have you tried setting the `onload`? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740860/load-events-for-embedded-elements) is very old, but seems to imply that works.

Comment: @DBS sorry for not referring to these, I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way the server could detect what the user is doing with their own(ed) materials. object or embed or iFrame should be the same. The PDF is ***automatically allowed for download so has been downloaded*** into sandbox, with a default option to view inline or disallowed to run by user choice of settings.

Here as a secured user You are not allowed to run JavaScript in my browsers So PDF will only open in a non JavaScript window and I can naturally modify/edit my html from your site.

[image]